# Is there a way to make gradient shadows?

Tags: shadows

Fairly new Blender user here. I'm using Blender Render for this next project of mine and I'm wondering if there is a way to make smoother shadows for these arches.

[image]

As you can see, within the arches, each block seems to get less dark, as opposed to a smooth shadow. It might have something to do with how it's built. It is three different pieces, the arches themselves, the block roof and some cubes that fill in the empty space.

[image]

Being new, I couldn't really figure out how else to do it, but any input you guys might have would be great! Thanks!

Comment: Hi. This may help with taking screenshots in future https://www.take-a-screenshot.org/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A fast and easy way to get smooth shadows on different faces is to set your object to smooth shading, then enable auto smooth and set a proper value (I usually use 66, it works fine on a lot of cases) :

[image]

*Smooth shading* modifies the normals (properties indicating how light behaves on your mesh) in order to make your faces look kind of if they were a unique surface instead of sharply defined faces.
*Auto Smooth* separates the faces forming a certain angle (above 66° here), this way you can easily let your face be sharp when they need to be. But it's an automated tool, It might not be enough on more complex geometry.

If you need more precision, you can "force" the shading to be smooth or sharp. For that, with Auto Smooth enabled, just enter edit mode, select some edges, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> and chose "Mark Smooth/Sharp" (note : in versions 2.79.x and 2.8x, these entries are in the "Edge Data" sub-menu).

Example here, I marked an edge as sharp on my cylinder:

[image]

And it's damn ugly. But it's for explanation sake!

If you're curious, I recommend you to check [Blender's manual about normals](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/normals.html).

About subdividing your mesh as mentioned by others, it completely depends on what you are doing, for what purpose, workflow, technical constraints, ... There are no absolute rules.
My advice is: If you don't need to add more mesh detail, don't add any.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

As L0Lock said, to smooth an object, you can simply click on *Smooth Shading* (in the *Tools* panel, on the right of your 3D View > *Tools* > *Shading* > *Smooth*) and enable the *Auto Smooth* option (*Properties* panel > *Data* > *Normals* > *Auto Smooth* and play with the *Angle* value).

My first answer was to use both *Smooth Shading* and *Subdivision Surface*. Why that? Because it won't only create a gradient shadow, it will also smooth your shape, which is generally what you want. In that case, no need for the *Auto Smooth*, but you will have to add some edge loops close to your angles to keep your angles sharp. That said you'll probably need to change your topology to make it work:

[image]

Comment: To get smooth shadows you only need to use shading tools like smooth shading. I would also use Auto smooth with a medium-low value (usually 66 works fine).
https://i.imgur.com/Ruu8pzS.png

Subdividing the mesh has nothing to do with that.

Comment: what you say is ok if you have a rather high-poly mesh, with the kind of topology he shows you will have a gradient but the silhouette will be angular, but you're right I'm going to precise this in my answer

Comment: What I say is for no matter what you are doing. The question is "I'm wondering if there is a way to make smoother shadows for these arches". Mesh resolution is completely off topic.

Comment: ok you should add your answer then

Comment: @L0Lock What you say is not true. You get shading artifacts on smoothed low poly meshes in Cycles. These are called terminator artifacts: https://developer.blender.org/T37814. So to get smooth shading you really need to crank up the subdivisions, moonboots approach is correct.

Comment: 1/ This kind of artifacts are not systematic. You shouldn't try to fix an artifact before it's there: you might never get it. 2/ Subdivision is only one way to fix this artifact (which again is not needed 'till you get said artifact and others solutions are not working or advantageous, so don't double your triangles for nothing). 3/ He's using Blender Internal. 4/ Getting arround artifacts is still off topic.

Comment: Subdividing a mesh when you just want to fix its shading is not common.

Comment: Not that if doing subdivision for a cleaner mesh, there is "edge crease" which is the correct way to get sharp edges. The extra edge loops have not been needed since ~2004, but somehow the recommendation persists.

Comment: @tschundler Hello tschundler, my answer was not very accurate here. That said I think Edge Crease may not always give a good result in some situations, that's why I prefer to use the good old bevel, but maybe elaborate a bit?

Comment: See, on the left, the edge is made with a bevel, on the right, with Edge Crease, it doesn't seem to work, how would you fix that? https://zupimages.net/up/23/29/zg3p.jpg

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "fix" - to me the one on the right looks more correct. I'm not sure the use case for a crease on an otherwise smooth surface that is not really an "edge". In that case, it's up to you an an artist what is best. But here, where there is a real edge, the edge crease will look good without extra polygons.

Comment: It was just an example, and in that example I wanted to show you that I couldn't do the same thing, in a lot of cases edge crease won't be able to give the desired result and you will need additional topology, also you can't control the width of the edge so much, and it's not compatible with some apps, etc, I think there are some reason why additional topology is still recommended